# Static files being served from the Django app instead of Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles

My website serves the static files from the Django app instead of the Nginx staticfiles folder but I can't figure out why.

My Django app static is on the (Linode) server at:

```
/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/myapp
```

The server static folder is at:

```
/var/www/html/staticfiles/myapp
```

Here's my `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/staticfiles/'
```

Here's my `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('myapp.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Here's my config file at `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`:

```
server {
    server_name helpmesaythis.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.105.76.53:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/html/staticfiles;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/helpmesaythis.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/helpmesaythis.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = helpmesaythis.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80;
    server_name helpmesaythis.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

I have restarted/reloaded Nginx and I have been using `collectstatic` without success.

I have also tried the following changes to the `default` file:

```
location /static {
        root /var/www/html/staticfiles;
    }

location /static/ {
        alias /var/www/html/staticfiles;
    }

location /static {
        alias /var/www/html/staticfiles;
    }
```

I have also tried putting the `location /static/` section above the `location /` section, just in case.

When I go to the staticfiles folder at `/var/www/html/staticfiles/myapp` there are a few files in their from when I first put the project on the server a few months ago, however none of the static files since then have gone in.

I only realised that this was happening recently when I saw that the audio files on my site were served as HTTP/1.1 instead of HTTP/2.

EDIT: I tried to open the following static file:

```
https://helpmesaythis.com/static/myapp/flag-spain.webp
```

And I got a 404 error. The Nginx error log states the following:

```
2023/03/27 14:59:10 [error] 18795#18795: *297 open() "/var/www/html/staticfilesmyapp/flag-spain.webp" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 181.237.132.46, server: helpmesaythis.com, request: "GET /static/myapp/flag-spain.webp HTTP/2.0", host: "helpmesaythis.com"
```

It makes sense as there is nothing in the server static folder as `python3 manage.py collectstatic` only collects the static files in the Django app directory.

Comment: The only good looking approach is with `alias` and matching trailing slash (both omitted or defined in location and alias definition). Please change nginx conf to this version, try to access a static file, update your question with specific file url and corresponding Nginx error log file data.

Comment: `location /static/ {alias /var/www/html/staticfiles/;}` this looks fine based on your description.

Comment: @IvanStarostin sorry when you say try to access a static file, what do you mean?

Comment: open static file url in browser

Comment: @IvanStarostin I've included those steps at the bottom of my original post

Comment: `staticfilesmyapp` trailing slash still not synchronized between location path and alias path.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Yes, my bad I missed that. After changing the config file and restarting Nginx, I did a `collectstatic`. Nothing was collected. So I manually moved all of the files in `/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/myapp` to `/var/www/html/staticfiles/myapp` and now the direct URL link to the static file works (https://helpmesaythis.com/static/myapp/flag-spain.webp). However, the website is still not loading the static files from that folder. It is loading them all from the app bucket still

Comment: Could it be because of these lines in my `settings.py`? `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'` and `STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'`?

Answer (score 0):

> When I go to the staticfiles folder at /var/www/html/staticfiles/myapp
> there are a few files in their from when I first put the project on
> the server a few months ago, however none of the static files since
> then have gone in.

Given this, my guess is that `collectstatic` fails to find the new files you added to the app. Why and how it got them the first time I don't know, as I wasn't there (maybe you copied the directory manually?), but it obviously isn't catching the new ones.

**Fastest solution is to copy them manually into the `/var/www/html/staticfiles/` directory**. This should fix it without further intervention.

However, if that's tedious and you want collectstatic to do it for you, then read ahead.

---

Set up the [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#std-setting-STATICFILES_DIRS) in `settings.py`, then re-run `collectstatic`.

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    "/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/myapp",
    # more directories ...
]
```

then:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Directories named `static` under apps that are correctly installed, should automatically be picked up by `collectstatic`, without having to be added to `STATICFILES_DIRS`. My guess as to why this isn't happening is possibly the weird reduntant structure of the folder `/myapp/static/myapp` (`myapp` twice). If the above `STATICFILES_DIRS` fix works, you might want to delete it, and refractor your tree correctly, like:

```
/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/css
/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/js
/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/* # etc...
```

---

Here are a few other things you can check:

- Make sure your new static files are located in a directory that's included in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. By default, this setting includes the static subdirectory in each app, but you can add additional directories if needed.
- Make sure your new static files have the correct naming and directory structure. By default, Django's `collectstatic` command expects static files to be located in a static subdirectory of each app, and to be named in a certain way (e.g. app_name/css/style.css). If your files are not named or structured correctly, collectstatic may not find them.
- Make sure your app is included in `INSTALLED_APPS`. If your app is not included in this setting, Django will not search its static files when running collectstatic.

If you've checked all of these settings and your static files are still not being collected, try running `collectstatic` with the `--traceback` option to see if there are any error messages that might explain the problem.

Comment: When I try to `collectstatic` with `STATICFILES_DIRS = ["/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/myapp",]` I get a warning saying that the directory doesn't exist. It's the same message if I try `STATICFILES_DIRS = ["/var/www/DjangoApp/myapp/static/",]` or even just `STATICFILES_DIRS = ["/static/",]`

Comment: The reason for the filepath `myapp -> static -> myapp` is the following: search 'Static file namespacing' within this page of the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

Comment: When I manually copy all of the files over to `/var/www/html/staticfiles/myapp` my website still gets all of the static files from the app, more specifically the bucket

Answer (score 0):

The static files problems were due to this in settings.py:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Which I changed to this:

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
```

This was a pretty silly oversight on my part. I think the problem was that when I made the change originally, and then did `collectstatic` on my local machine, it threw up an error because the path in `STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/html/staticfiles/'` obviously isn't on my local machine. However, after pushing through the change and doing `collectstatic` on my server, everything worked as it should.